# Can't install "car" package in R on Mac

Tags: r, install.packages

- R version 3.6.1
- R studio version 1.2.5033
- Mac OS Catalina version 10.15.3

When I tried to install "car" in Rstudio

```
> install.packages("car")
Installing package into ‘/Users/wuxiaowen/Library/R/3.6/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘SparseM’, ‘minqa’, ‘RcppEigen’, ‘pbkrtest’, ‘quantreg’, ‘lme4’

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘SparseM’ ‘minqa’ ‘RcppEigen’ ‘quantreg’ ‘lme4’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel)
```

When i selected Yes, it will download the packages, and then generate lots lots of lines of codes... The last a few lines are:

```
17 warnings generated.
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o RcppEigen.so RcppEigen.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o init.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [RcppEigen.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/Users/wuxiaowen/Library/R/3.6/library/RcppEigen’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘SparseM’ is not available for package ‘quantreg’
* removing ‘/Users/wuxiaowen/Library/R/3.6/library/quantreg’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘quantreg’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘minqa’, ‘RcppEigen’ are not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/Users/wuxiaowen/Library/R/3.6/library/lme4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘pbkrtest’
* removing ‘/Users/wuxiaowen/Library/R/3.6/library/pbkrtest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘pbkrtest’, ‘quantreg’, ‘lme4’ are not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/Users/wuxiaowen/Library/R/3.6/library/car’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/rd/lm38rxvn2_9c80f7062hk5s80000gn/T/RtmpfzTlj3/downloaded_packages’
```

If I selected "no", it shows:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘pbkrtest’
* removing ‘/Users/wuxiaowen/Library/R/3.6/library/pbkrtest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘pbkrtest’, ‘quantreg’, ‘lme4’ are not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/Users/wuxiaowen/Library/R/3.6/library/car’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/rd/lm38rxvn2_9c80f7062hk5s80000gn/T/RtmpfzTlj3/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried one of suggestions I found online by installing Xcode, but it didn't seem to solve the problem...Please help. Thanks!

Comment: you needa install gcc.. check this out https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error/#after-r-3-4-0

Comment: I think i used homebrew to install gcc etc.. you can also try the other options

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much. I have no idea what gcc does but i downloaded the installer here https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases and was able to install the package in R. Thanks!